# I have position but z index is not working

Tags: html, css, z-index

i want the outside ring to go behind the circle, but when I tried to use `z-index` its not working. not doing anything. I made 2 rings, one ring is on top of the circle without the top, the other one is behind the circle I just can't move it i don't know why.

```css
:root{
  --size:200px;
}
#background {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: linear-gradient(-23.5deg, #000033, #00001a);
  z-index:-2;
}

#background #mainplanet {
  width:var(--size);
  height:var(--size);
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius:50%;
}

#background #mainplanet:before,#background #mainplanet:after{
  content:"";
  width:calc(var(--size) * 1.5);
  height:calc(var(--size) / 2);
  border:30px solid #000;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:-80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform: rotateX(66deg) rotateY(170deg);
}

#background #mainplanet:before{
  border-top-color:transparent;
}

#background #mainplanet:after{
  z-index:-3;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="mainplanet">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the transform and replace it with something else and you will  be able to move the pseudo-element behind:

```css
:root{
  --size:200px;
}
#background {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: linear-gradient(-23.5deg, #000033, #00001a);
  z-index:-2;
}

#background #mainplanet {
  width:var(--size);
  height:var(--size);
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  top:calc(50% - var(--size)/2);
  left:calc(50% - var(--size)/2);
  border-radius:50%;
}

#background #mainplanet:before,#background #mainplanet:after{
  content:"";
  width:calc(var(--size) * 1.5);
  height:calc(var(--size) / 2);
  border:30px solid #000;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:-80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform: rotateX(66deg) rotateY(170deg);
}

#background #mainplanet:before{
  border-top-color:transparent;
}

#background #mainplanet:after{
  z-index:-3;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="mainplanet">
  </div>
</div>
```

As we may read in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-css-position-3-20160517/#painting-order):

> 8. All **positioned**, opacity or **transform descendants**, in tree order that fall into the following categories:
>
>    1. All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0', in tree order. For those with 'z-index: auto', treat the element as if it created a new stacking context, **but any positioned descendants and descendants which actually create a new stacking context should be considered part of the parent stacking context**, not this new one.  For those with 'z-index: 0' treat the stacking context generated atomically.
>    2. All opacity descendants with opacity less than 1, in tree order, create a stacking context generated atomically.
>    3. All transform descendants with transform other than none, in tree order, **create a stacking context generated atomically**.

So the trick here is to avoid the positioned pseudo-element to belong to its parent stacking context to able to place it considering an upper stacking context thus it can be placed **behind its parent**.

So the parent element should not have `z-index` specified, opacity less than 1, use `transform`, etc.

[Full list of the properties that create stacking context.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context#The_stacking_context)