# Absolute div got covered by translated element

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve but have been stuck so far.

I have a table that I use a little trick on it; this results in my table contains the style of

```
"transform: translate(0,0)"
```

for a bunch of cells. This is where the problem occurs. I'm having a tooltip in it, which requires position absolute to work. But so far, the tooltip got completely hidden by the translated element. You can see the problem through this:

```css
th, td {
  padding: 20px
}

#cell {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.translate {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>  
  <body>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th><p>Hi</p></th>
         <th class="parent translate">
           <p>Hello</p>
           <div class="overflow">Overflow text</div>
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>hello cell</td>
        <td class="translate" id="cell">hello cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>    
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this problem? I have tried everything that I have thought of :(. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply increase the `z-index` of the parent element

```css
th, td {
  padding: 20px
}

#cell {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.translate {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>  
  <body>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th><p>Hi</p></th>
         <th class="parent translate">
           <p>Hello</p>
           <div class="overflow">Overflow text</div>
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>hello cell</td>
        <td class="translate" id="cell">hello cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>    
  </body>
</html>
```

You are facing the logical result of the [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order) where the transformed element are painted after the positioned one since it comes later in the DOM tree and since there is no `z-index` specified.

---

Also note that adding `z-index` to the tooltip won't work because transform create a stacking context so `z-index` will place the tooltip inside that stacking context which is already placed below the `#cell`.

```css
th, td {
  padding: 20px
}

#cell {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.translate {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>  
  <body>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th><p>Hi</p></th>
         <th class="parent translate">
           <p>Hello</p>
           <div class="overflow">Overflow text</div>
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>hello cell</td>
        <td class="translate" id="cell">hello cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>    
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Related questions for more details:

['transform3d' not working with position: fixed children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15194313/8620333)

[Why elements with any z-index value can never cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

[I have position but z index is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51603351/8620333)